# Deriving a momentum proposal distribution for Hamiltonian Monte Carlo -- non-Gaussian kinetic energies

Tags: hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I am trying to understand how to derive the optimal way to generate momenta in HMC.

In the gaussian case, I think the approach is that if one samples proportional to the Gaussian, the log likelihoods have a chi² distribution, and to generate this, one can sample from a Gaussian. This takes care of the individual directions and the normalisation, such that all energy levels are explore proportionally.

In a flat top distribution case, I can also take samples, and compare their log-likelihood (probability density to marginal likelihood), which is a constant. So to generate momenta, I can choose a fixed normalisation, and random direction, i.e., sample from a gaussian, and normalise the length.

In this case I suppose the situation is time-invariant -- the step length defines the time intervals. However, I suppose the total energy injected is an important normalisation(?).

If I have a general distribution -- lets say I understand it analytically, but still want to HMC it -- is the approach to imagine sampling from the distribution, looking at the energy levels / log likelihood distribution, and that should be the momenta normalisation (combined with a random direction)?

There is the additional aspect of choosing the directions following covariance matrices, but I think I grasp that.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means "generating momenta". Which part of the algorithm are you referring to?

Comment: Choosing directions and step length for the trajectory. Typically, one draws a vector using d normal distributions, such that they have the covariance of the target distribution. This assumes a Gaussian-ish target. I want to know how I can insert, if I know my distribution is shaped differently, that knowledge.